# Google keyboard doesn't call commitText() on pressing Enter

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have written a custom `InputConnection` by extending android's BaseInputConnection. I used to get `commitText()` when the user presses Enter Key. But recently with Google Keyboard, this doesn't happen. Google Keyboard sends `sendKeyEvent()` with the parameter being enterKeyUp and enterKeyDown events. However, I don't get the predicted text, as I used to get in `commitText()`. How can I get the predicted text on pressing EnterKey in Googke Keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Did they actually have a composing region?  If not they may have decided no commit text was necessary.  Or did you tell them your input type was NULL?  If so, they may have gone into dumb mode and sent everything as key events.

They also may have called FinishComposingText instead, which tells the editor that the existing text is good (no correction).  But its generally not a good idea to assume a certain action will come from a certain event because keyboards are always working around bugs in bad input connection implementations to get the effect they want.  Just implement InputConnection as best you can and do what it says, rather than expect certain events at certain times.